# How to Change the Pin Number in Adafruit_TFTLCD

Tags: arduino, lcd, adafruit

I am trying to make a GUI with [ACEIRMC 3.5" IPS TFT LCD Display](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089ZWV9JS) using Adafruit_TFTLCD, [rotary encoder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F26CT6B) and
[16x2 LCD display](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BPY9J5NJ) using arduino mega 2560.
It says like this (Part of it):

```
// For the Arduino Mega, use digital pins 22 through 29
// (on the 2-row header at the end of the board).
//   D0 connects to digital pin 22
//   D1 connects to digital pin 23
//   D2 connects to digital pin 24
//   D3 connects to digital pin 25
//   D4 connects to digital pin 26
//   D5 connects to digital pin 27
//   D6 connects to digital pin 28
//   D7 connects to digital pin 29
```

However, I would like to use those pins for 16x2 LCD display.
Could anyone help me change
D0 to digital pin 8,
D1 to digital pin 9,
D2 to digital pin 2,
D3 to digital pin 3,
D4 to digital pin 4,
D5 to digital pin 5,
D6 to digital pin 6,
and D7 to digital pin 7?

And I want to display [7 segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display) and [unicode characters](https://home.unicode.org/).

I checked the Adafruit_TFTLCD.h and Adafruit_TFTLCD.cpp, however, I don't know where they are.